# Regex for matching all words containing Exactly two letter e's and between 1 and 3 letter a's

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

How would one write a regex to match this:

> Regex matching all words containing exactly two letter e's and between 1 and 3 letter a's

I have no idea where to even start, my thoughts would be to use lookahead; but, how do I apply lookahead twice to this problem? Is that even possible?

Comment: Start at [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970). Then, do not forget to check [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: it would be easier to use a 2-pass flow: first find all the ones with `e`s, then filter() all those for `a`s.

Comment: Your link is not very helpful Wiktor, I am familiar with regular expression syntax in its basics. 

dandavis, is it possible to solve this just writing one regular expression? I would have approached it using that technique too but say there is an acamdemic constraint to just use one regular expression for it

Comment: So, @Display, what have you tried? Give it a shot in a [regex tester](http://regex101.com/) and then we can help you from there.

Comment: hint: `(?=TEST1)(?=TEST2).+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hunch to use lookahead twice is good.  Here is a solution:

```
((?=\b(?:[a-df-z0-9_]*e[a-df-z0-9_]*){2}\b)(?=\b(?:[b-z0-9_]*a[b-z0-9_]*){1,3}\b).+)
```

[Here is the same regex with token explanation on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iW7uX8/2).